# Beam python sdk - save_main_session - DoFn imports - what are the best practices?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a question about `save_main_session` and best practices, and please let me know if there is a doc somewhere that covers this question. So with `save_main_session` set to `False`, if my `DoFn` in the `process` method uses for example standard lib `copy` module, Beam's `FileSystems` API or my custom module, if I import those at the module level (top of the file) in which the `DoFn` is defined, this would fail in Dataflow service with an error that says that `copy` (etc) module was not found from the `process` method (which all makes sense), and I could fix this by either:

1. importing `copy` inside the process method
2. "saving" `copy` reference/object as a field/provider/etc in the `DoFn` instance
3. setting `save_main_session` to `True`

I don't want to set `save_main_session` to `True` because afaiu it captures whole main session and I have bunch of objects that are not serializable in there, and overall find `save_main_session` to be smelly and hacky. 1st option is kinda smelly as well and doesn't always work - tho imports are cached so performance wise should be okish - but it would not work for my custom modules afaiu (unless I explicitly install/send them over to the workers). And lastly 2nd is kinda hacky - working around the Beam framework.

I'm leaning mostly towards the 2nd option, but it just doesn't feel right to no be able to just use the global imports and workaround it be adding and using instance field(s).

What is the best practice for this problem? I know the examples are suggesting to set `save_main_session` to `True`, but that again has consequences and just smells. Are there better options?

Comment: You can also workaround this issue by using dill in a recursive/recurse mode, see my comment here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/219#issuecomment-522068603

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#programming_with_the_sdk_for_python), if you have objects in your global namespace that cannot be pickled, you will get a pickling error. If the error is regarding a module that should be available in the Python distribution, you can solve this by importing the module locally, where it is used.

Answer (score -1):

The `DoFn` class comes with a `setup` method that is called once per `DoFn` instance. You can override this method, and perform your imports there.

---

As a note, this method is available in Beam's Python release for 2.13.0. If you're using an earlier version, you can override `start_bundle` in your `DoFn` to perform the import there.

Comment: that is not going to solve the problem of exposing those imports "globally" for a whole DoFn content/funs/etc correct? Therefor it's not really an answer to the question - right? Am I missing something?